# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField and CheckboxSelectMultiple delete values

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Form with:

```
somemodels = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=SomeModel.objects.none, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

I set my queryset with my __init__ function and and can even provide existing connections to my list on page load (existing objects are marked as checked).

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       qs = kwargs.pop('SomeModel')
       inital_object = kwargs.pop('someothermodel')
       super(SelectDatesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['timeframes'].queryset = qs
       selected_items = qs.filter(someothermodels=inital_object) #manytomany relationship
       self.fields['somemodels'].initial = selected_timframes
```

The issue I get is a combination of the fact that a) HTML only submits data for checked inputs and b) django forms remove all the already existing objects from "cleaned_data".

When I submit the form, I get the **cleaned_data** list of my form only contains the newly selected values, not the ones that were already selected when the page was constructed.

To delete the existing ones (i.e. if the user unselects a checkbox that was initially checked) I need to know either a) a total list of all selected values, or b) a list of values that have been unselected.

Is there a smooth way of doing this without actually going through the original POST data?